# Multiple choice listview

Tags: android, android-listview

i developed a multiple choice listview, my question is how i can make a if statemen or swicth to the position when checkboxes are checked.

I have been looking on internet and i found some examples but is not what im lookinf for.

for example this code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    String selected = "";
    int cntChoice = myList.getCount();

    SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray = myList.getCheckedItemPositions();

    for(int i = 0; i < cntChoice; i++){
        if(sparseBooleanArray.get(i)) {
            selected += myList.getItemAtPosition(i).toString() + "\n";
        }
    }

    Toast.makeText(AndroidListViewActivity.this, selected, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

What is does is take all checked checkbox from the multiple choice putting then into an array. My questios is how i can identify which is it, and depending which is check do something or not.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

By default not. Checking the source code you can see the follow:

```
512     @Override
513     public boolean performItemClick(View v, int position, long id) {
514         // Ignore clicks in header/footers
515         if (isHeaderOrFooterPosition(position)) {
516             // Clicked on a header/footer, so ignore pass it on to super
517             return super.performItemClick(v, position, id);
518         }
519         
520         // Internally handle the item click
521         final int adjustedPosition = getFlatPositionForConnector(position);
522         return handleItemClick(v, adjustedPosition, id);
523     }

533         boolean handleItemClick(View v, int position, long id) {
534         final PositionMetadata posMetadata = mConnector.getUnflattenedPos(position);
535         
536         id = getChildOrGroupId(posMetadata.position);
537         
538         boolean returnValue;
539         if (posMetadata.position.type == ExpandableListPosition.GROUP) {
540             /* It's a group, so handle collapsing/expanding */
                ...
579         } else {
580             /* It's a child, so pass on event */
581             if (mOnChildClickListener != null) {
582                 playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);
583                 return mOnChildClickListener.onChildClick(this, v, posMetadata.position.groupPos,
584                         posMetadata.position.childPos, id);
585             }
586 
587             returnValue = false;
588         }
589 
590         posMetadata.recycle();
591 
592         return returnValue;
593     }
```

Source:
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/widget/ExpandableListView.java#ExpandableListView.handleItemClick%28android.view.View%2Cint%2Clong%29

The problem here is if the row is not header neither footer, the method performItemClick of super class (android.widget.AbsListView) won't be called, which is the one who takes account the choice mode:
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/widget/AbsListView.java#AbsListView.performItemClick%28android.view.View%2Cint%2Clong%29

So, the unique solution is implement the choice logic in onChildItemClickListener ourself. Here is the sample code for Multiple choice:

https://github.com/jiahaoliuliu/ExpandableListViewMultipleChoice

This issue could be duplicated:
[Is choiceMode compatible with ExpandableListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815654/is-choicemode-compatible-with-expandablelistview/18616138#18616138)